# Debian: unable to install lsb package

Tags: drivers, printing, proprietary-drivers, lsb

I have an Epson ET-2600 printer at home. I tried configuring it using CUPS, but the printing is very slow and constantly in a very high quality (which results in a lot of ink being wasted). I tried to download the .deb packages [from here](http://download.ebz.epson.net/dsc/du/02/DriverDownloadInfo.do?LG2=EN&CN2=&DSCMI=98326&DSCCHK=2524fdd59c65d800a41ac10bc07b94b635ee89b7), but **it requires the `lsb` package** which I cannot retrieve. I currently have Debian 10 installed. I tried to put in my `/etc/apt/sources.list` the link for Debian Jessie and running `sudo apt install lsb`, but it did not work.

Any ideas on how I can get a better working open driver or the lsb package to install the official Epson driver?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Did you run `apt update` first?

Comment: @Panki yes. It did not work because of a library which had some errors during installation. Then I read that lsb was deprecated and I decided to look somewhere else.

Answer (score 3):

The package `lsb` is deprecated , debian recommend to create the `deb` package through alien (from `rpm`):

e,g ([redhat-lsb](https://pkgs.org/download/lsb)):

```
sudo apt install alien
wget http://mirror.centos.org/centos/8/AppStream/x86_64/os/Packages/redhat-lsb-4.1-47.el8.x86_64.rpm
sudo alien --to-deb -c redhat-lsb-4.1-47.el8.x86_64.rpm
sudo apt install ./redhat-lsb_4.1-48_amd64.deb
```

> Debian discontinued LSB support in 2015 ...
>
> LSB applications are provided in either the RPM package format or in an LSB-compliant self-installing executable. In the case of RPM packages, use the alien(1) tool to convert the rpm to a Debian package and then install normally. Make sure to use the `-c` option to alien to ensure that package scripts are converted as well.

[Debian LSB](https://wiki.debian.org/DebianLsb)

Comment: I tried to install lsb with your method, but the .deb installer of my printer's driver still complains about the fact that lsb is missing... however, I noticed that the package name is redhat-lsb and not lsb: could this be the reason of that complaining?

Comment: @LuxGiammi have you installed the required package? `redhat-lsb-printing` ... https://centos.pkgs.org/8/centos-appstream-x86_64/redhat-lsb-4.1-47.el8.x86_64.rpm.html

Answer (score 2):

LSB or Linux Standard Base support in Debian has been discontinued as of [2015](https://lwn.net/Articles/658809/)
. They have kept some of the features in the packages [`lsb-base`](https://packages.debian.org/buster/lsb-base) and [`lsb-release`](https://packages.debian.org/buster/lsb-release).

While not especially dangerous, I would recommend that you stick to only using Debian stable repositories and remove the Jessie sources from your `/etc/apt/sources.list`. After you have done that (and updated apt with `apt update`), you can install these packages with `apt install lsb-base lsb-release`.

Now test installing your printer drivers and see if they work.

However, I am not sure if this will provide the necessary LSB feature set that your printer may need. You can also choose to go to the [LSB main site](https://wiki.linuxfoundation.org/lsb/start) and download and install the latest version of LSB manually if necessary.

I will recommend that if you need to support specific hardware not supported by Debian it may be best to change over to a Linux distro that supports your hardware. Your printer currently works using CUPS, however you are complaining that the configuration wastes ink and print jobs takes too long. You should look into or ask about how to get your CUPS configuration to a more desirable state if this solution does not work.

Comment: Thanks for your reply. I already have lsb-base and lsb-release installed on my computer (apt confirms), but the .deb package of my printer driver still complains about the missing lsb package. I'm going to try the manual installation of that package. Is lsb deprecated in _all_ linux distributions or just in Debian?

Comment: @LuxGiammi  I only looked into LSB on Debian because of your question. So only Debian as far as I know. However, many distributions are based on Debian and may choose to not package LSB themselves. It looks like user GAD3R's answer provides a solution to taking the rpm LSB package and converting it to a format Debian can use. I would go with that if you absolutely require Debian but it looks like Fedora/CentOS has that package available in their repos if you are able to easily change OS.

Answer (score 1):

My take: I installed an `lsb-compat` forward port deb package package which provides `lsb`. I downloaded it from an MX Linux forum: https://forum.mxlinux.org/viewtopic.php?f=104&t=55746&hilit=lsb+compat#p555628

I was able to install the `epson-inkjet-printer-scpr` and the `epson-printer-utility` packages obtained from Epson after that. Shame on the printer manufacturers that they make us go through such hoops.

For the record I'm using https://devuan.org/ ceres, so I'm not with Linux Mint. Devuan is a Debian derivative.

Answer (score 1):

I had the same issue, but it's very simple to repair.

Example: If you want the drivers for Epson SX410
Go to the official website

> http://download.ebz.epson.net/dsc/search/01/search/searchModule

And download your driver.

After download lsb_compat from here

> https://debian.pkgs.org/9/debian-main-amd64/lsb-compat_9.20161125_amd64.deb.html

Now type on terminal

```
sudo dpkg -i lsb-compat_9.20161125_amd64.deb
```

After you will have this error

```
lsb-compat depends from zlib1g:i386
```

Type

```
sudo apt install lib32z1
```

And automatically this set epson drivers ! :)

Comment: The link to pkgs.org is no longer valid. But on https://packages.debian.org/stretch/lsb-compat you can still find the package.
After the error about missing dependencies `apt install -f` was enough for me to install those.

Comment: The location of lsb_compat from debian archives is the following: https://archive.debian.org/debian/pool/main/l/lsb/lsb-compat_9.20161125_amd64.deb

Answer (score 1):

As for 2023, it seems lsb-compat (deb package) has been deleted from every archive I searched for.

I still have a copy that works, as a hope that someone in the future may need it. I'll upload it.

Try:

```
sudo apt install -y wget
wget https://archive.org/download/lsb-compat_9.20161125_amd64/lsb-compat_9.20161125_amd64.deb
sudo apt install ./lsb-compat_9.20161125_amd64.deb
```

Hopefully, this helps someone someday.